# Dynamic Dashboard with Large Dataset in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, dataset, dashboard, large-data

I created an **excel** **dashboard** that is feeding on 100 pivot table and source data is approximately 700k and it will grow more every month.

In my dashboard, there are list boxes which are changing the source data and if source data changes, pivot tables are refreshing and the dashboard is filling with new values. I created this **dynamic** report because the users want to change something and see the results.

So, my problems are excel document is really high(160 MB), execution time (changing data source and refreshing pivot tables) is long and I am not sure whether excel can handle these data or not in the following days because the data is growing. Do you know any solution to maintain my report stably? I know R, Python, Access but I do not know the how can I create a dynamic dashboard in excel if the data is large.

I created **MS Access** table but as you see in the second pic I have a list box and this affect the source table of pivots. How can I send it the cell value to **MS Access** to calculate new column dynamically and after calculation change pivot and fill dashboard? In the third picture, you can see source data and calculated column in excel but I want to use this in the **MS Access**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3dSI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sAuG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwAwJ.png)

Comment: I would recommend something like a SQL database (and not Access). You can then query the database to update your **dashboard**. There are a dew examples of how you can query the database. Also, SQL is designed to handle large data where Access has limitations

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Zac. But as I mentioned above, some columns of the dataset are changing when the user changes the value of **list boxes**. Is automatic updating columns of SQL database according to changes of excel list boxes possible?

Comment: Yes it is. It's just like you would do it in any database (including access). You just run an `UPDATE` query. Saying that, depending on what you need to do and how, you could potentially save data in your worksheet and do a singular update to database

Comment: I want to establish a structure that is 1) loading data into Access 2) when the select a month or country in the excel, one column of Access data is calculated using this value which is coming from excel 3) I will create a pivot using access data (loaded data and calculated column, both of them) 4) pivot results will fill the dashboard. However, I couldn't create a calculated column in the access that uses the value is coming from excel.